# reference in visualforce the lookup field on child record in master detail

Tags: visualforce, lookup, controller-extension, master-detail, childrecords

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!oldSubscriptionAndAsset}" var="assetAndSubs">
     <apex:column>
           <apex:facet name="header">Asset</apex:facet>
           <apex:outputText value="{!assetAndSubs.SBQQ__Asset__r.Name}"/>
     </apex:column>
     <apex:column>
           <apex:facet name="header">Asset</apex:facet>
           <apex:outputText value="{!assetAndSubs.SBQQ__Product__r.Name}"/>
     </apex:column> 
</apex:pageBlockTable>

oldSubscriptionAndAsset =[SELECT Id, SBQQ__Product__r.Name, SBQQ__Quantity__c,(SELECT Id, SBQQ__Asset__r.Name, SBQQ__Asset__r.SerialNumber, SBQQ__Asset__r.Is_Selected_For_Renewal__c  FROM SBQQ__SubscribedAssets__r) FROM SBQQ__Subscription__c];
```

I have a master detail relationship, Subscription(Master) and SubscribedAsset(Child), in my visualforce page, I want to show in different column the subscription name (master), name of the asset in lookup field Asset__c in SubscribedAsset(child record). So that, every subscription has many asset. My problem is, how could I reference the lookup fields of child records on different column? what will be the exact 'value' for the output text?

Comment: Hi boy george, welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to scroll through the [tour] and read [ask]. Right now this post does not contain any question, which makes it very difficult to assist you. Can you please **[edit]** your post to clarify what you are trying to achieve and where you are stuck?

Comment: Your edit is an improvement, but you still do not ask any question nor clearly indicate where you are stuck. It seems like the markup you have already gets a parent value in the column.

Comment: You appear to be iterating over a list of `SBQQ__Subscription__c`, each record within which has detail objects within `SBQQ__SubscribedAssets__r`, and what you want is to reference a field on one of the detail objects. If that is correct, you need a nested iteration - or possible a `LIMIT 1` on your query; it's not clear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: yes I want to reference a lookup field on the detail object. How could I apply the nested iteration there?

Answer (score 2):

What's happening here is that each `SBQQ__Subscription__c` in `oldSubscriptionAndAsset` has a property `SBQQ__SubscribedAssets__r`, whose value is a `List`. What you are trying to reference is a property `SBQQ__Product__r.Name` on the objects contained in that list.

You cannot do that with `oldSubscriptionAndAsset.SBQQ__Product__r.Name`, because that is not a property of the type `SBQQ__Subscription__c`. You also cannot do `oldSubscriptionAndAsset.SBQQ__SubscribedAssets__r.SBQQ__Product__r.Name`, because `oldSubscriptionAndAsset.SBQQ__SubscribedAssets__r` is also a `List`.

To access this property, you must be iterating over the child objects in `SBQQ__SubscribedAssets__r`. You can do this in two ways, and it's not clear from your question which one is correct.

1. You can use a nested iteration, where you use an outer loop (probably an `<apex:repeat>`; you can't use an `<apex:pageBlockTable>` as an outer loop here) to iterate over the `SBQQ__Subscription__c` records in `oldSubscriptionAndAsset`. Then, you can use an inner loop, which could be an `<apex:pageBlockTable>`, to iterate over the list `oldSubscriptionAndAsset.SBQQ__SubscribedAssets__r`. Inside the inner iteration, you can access properties like `SBQQ__Product__r.Name` through its iteration variable.
2. If your Visualforce page is really only looking at the children of a single `SBQQ__Subscription__c` record, you can change your query. If you change the type of `oldSubscriptionAndAsset` from `List<SBQQ__Subscription__c>` to `SBQQ__Subscription__c` and query for exactly one record, you no longer need a nested iteration. you would then do

`SBQQ__Subscription__c oldSubscriptionAndAsset = [SELECT Id, SBQQ__Product__r.Name, SBQQ__Quantity__c,(SELECT Id, SBQQ__Asset__r.Name, SBQQ__Asset__r.SerialNumber, SBQQ__Asset__r.Is_Selected_For_Renewal__c  FROM SBQQ__SubscribedAssets__r) FROM SBQQ__Subscription__c WHERE Id = :SOME_ID LIMIT 1];`

The `value` attribute on your `<apex:pageBlockTable>` would then be `{! oldSubscriptionAndAsset.SBQQ__SubscribedAssets__r }`, and your columns could directly reference properties of the child objects.

Comment: how could I apply on single row the parent record on first column(that will display as single because it's only 1 parent record here), and on second column will be the related child records(that will be multiple) in visualforce page?

Comment: You still need two iteration components, but one of them would be nested in a column and iterate over `SBQQ__SubscribedAssets__r`.

Comment: can you guide me on that by giving an example?

Comment: I would recommend reading in detail the references on `<apex:repeat>` and `<apex:pageBlockTable>`. I'm afraid I don't have an example handy.

Comment: I've already tried that one, but still displaying many parent record.

Comment: It's not about trying one component or another. You have a one-to-many relationship in your data model, and your page needs to explicitly handle that by iterating over the child objects.